# Creating Pandas DF from lists

Tags: pandas, valueerror

Im attempting to create a pandas dataframe out of list of lists that contain 1402 values for each of 216439 data points. Im using the pandas.DataFrame method and passing in the list of lists and a list of feature names of equal length.
But its throwing an error that
'Shape of passed values is (216439, 1402), indices imply (1402, 1402)'

```
`#call the fittransform method with the new encoder object
transformed_deposit = deposit_transformer.fit_transform(deposit_features)
transformed_deposit = transformed_deposit.toarray()
#create a data frame using transformed data and column names from get feature names out method 

transformed_deposit_df = pd.DataFrame(
    transformed_deposit, 
    deposit_transformer.get_feature_names_out()
)`
```

## I've tried changing the data types and verifying the length of the column names is the same as the number of elements in the list matches 1402.

Comment: Pls post sample of your lists

Comment: Need sample data. Reading [ask] and [mre] will likely increase chances of getting answers. Taking the [tour] is also quite informative. Then we'll help with the formatting :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the shape is (216439, 1402), then you should pass your 1402 IDs as columns, not as index:

```
transformed_deposit_df = pd.DataFrame(
    transformed_deposit, 
    columns=deposit_transformer.get_feature_names_out()
)
```

Or, if you want the index then transpose:

```
transformed_deposit_df = pd.DataFrame(
    transformed_deposit.T, 
    deposit_transformer.get_feature_names_out()
```